# ¿Por qué no se centra el div?

Tags: html, css

**Estoy empezando a diseñar una pagina web** y ya he tenido los primeros problemas. Soy bastante nuevo en esto del php así que ruego clemencia.

**Mi objetivo es tener un div** (PageTopWrap) **centrado en la cabecera** (PageTop), para que mis objetos de la cabecera, como por ejemplo el logo queden centrados dentro de este div, y que no salgan en un extremo, que es lo que me está pasando y no entiendo porque.

Este es **mi código**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=" UTF-8">
<title> Titulo de la Pagina </title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {margin: 0px;}
#pageTop {
  background: url(style/header.png) repeat-x;
  heigh: 90px;
}
#pageTop > #PageTopWrap {
  width: 900px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#pageTop > #PageTopWrap > #PageTopLogo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
}
</style>                  
</head> 
<body>
<div id="pageTop">
  <div id="pageTopWrap">
        <div id="pageTopLogo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></img>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="pageMiddle"></div>
<div id="pageBottom"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar tienes un problema de mayúsculas, el id del div `pageTopLogo` lo tienes con la `p` minúscula y en tu css tienes la `P` mayúscula.

En segundo lugar le he agregado una propiedad mas a tu estilo para el `pageTopLogo`

`text-align: center;`

**Resultado;**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=" UTF-8">
<title> Titulo de la Pagina </title>
<style type="text/css">
body {margin: 0px;}
#pageTop {
  background: url(style/header.png) repeat-x;
  height: 90px;
}
#pageTop > #PageTopWrap {
  width: 900px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#pageTop > #PageTopWrap > #PageTopLogo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
}
</style>                  
</head> 
<body>
<div id="pageTop">
  <div id="PageTopWrap">
        <div id="pageTopLogo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></img>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="pageMiddle"></div>
<div id="pageBottom"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tambien te recomiendo leer las recomendaciones de la W3C para que trabajes sin problemas con CSS

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.w3.org/People/Schepers/spec-conventions.html)

Comment: Funciona, muchas gracias!! Errores del primer día... me miraré W3C

Comment: @AdriadeJuan Excelente, recuerda marcar como `aceptada` la respuesta.

Comment: También te sirve Display: flex;  justify content: center; una manera más profesional y moderna de hacerlo

Comment: @Header90 si, existe mas de un camino para llegar a roma, también puede usar Grid que es mas profesional que `Display: flex; justify content: center;` pero no se le puede complicar ya que esta iniciando y no posee conocimiento de esos conceptos.